# 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting' causes error to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions', any solution?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

**Behind the problem**

I want to store my connection sting using the 'Users Secret' feature on Visual Studio 2022. To do this the following extensions must be installed:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The code solution works on its own, and I am now trying to implement it on another solution. By doing so it creates the following error

`function is in error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0`
OR [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65aG0.png) .

**What I have managed so far:**

I have managed to narrow it down to the following extension to cause the problem:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />`

This extension used for managing Users Secret and is necessary to have in the code.

I have managed to try a few examples from Google, but without luck. I now ask here in hope that anyone have a solution to this problem.

I cannot see a relation between those two extensions, and why it causes the problem.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade all your packages and start upgrading them one by one and run the app after each upgrade until you reach the maximum version of each package before you get the error.

I had similar issue and I had to do that and upgrading them one by one to find two packages are causing this and had to leave at a lower version in order to not get that error

Comment: By downgrading 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting' to 6.0.1 and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions' to 6.0.0 solved my problem. Thank  you.